# How to replicate CREATE USER command?

Tags: replication, mariadb

I'm replicating database master to master and everything works ok except for mysql.user table.

When I create user in DB-1, that user is not created om DB-2.

I have this on both servers in cnf

```
binlog_ignore_db=information_schema
binlog_ignore_db=performance_schema
binlog_ignore_db=ssl

binlog_do_db=mysql

replicate_do_db=mysql
replicate_do_table=mysql.user
```

Status is showing that replication is ok.

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G
```

Thank you for help.

**EDIT 1:**
I have also tried to sync all databases:

```
binlog_do_db=mysql
binlog_do_db=information_schema
binlog_do_db=performance_schema
binlog_do_db=ssl

replicate_do_db=mysql
replicate_do_db=information_schema
replicate_do_db=performance_schema
replicate_do_db=ssl
```

**EDIT 2:**

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.26-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: User creation involves not only `mysql.user` table but `replicate_do_table` directive(s) excludes all tables not mentioned from the replication. It's not a good idea to replicate the `mysql` database partially.

Comment: @Kondybas tried with removing line replicate_do_table=mysql.user, but user is still not created on other server

Comment: Have you synchronized both servers before starting slaves?

Comment: @Kondybas - yes

Comment: @Kondybas here it says only CREATE USER is working https://serverfault.com/a/721139/184573 but I'm using that command so that is not problem

Comment: I see in binlog on one server and in relay on another query for creating user

Comment: @Kondybas updated my question

Comment: Maybe you want to look for syncronous replication (clustering)

Comment: @vegatripy tnx, I will take a look

Comment: @vegatripy solved

Comment: @Kondybas solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
Before command CREATE USER you have to put:

```
use mysql;
```

and then it is replicated to slave server

Comment: `CREATE USER` do not need to be prepended with `USE mysql` as it works with it anyway. I suspect that your internal databases and tables are broken enough and you have to reinit your server to avoid unforeseen consequences. N.B. Information and performance schemas are internal engines that shouldn't be replicated.

Comment: @Kondybas - no. fres Ubuntu 16.04 with fresh database. Slave VM cloned and configured. replication works for all dbs except for "mysql" db which does not throw any error. After I put use mysql it works.  found solution here https://www.fromdual.com/mysql-replication-with-filtering-is-dangerous

Comment: @iWizard aren't you afraid of revealing password in plain text in binary log files? Are you using SSL? You don't want to send passwords over an unsecured network.
Why do you want to replicate mysql database anyway? I prefer to skip all of the system databases including mysql. This way I can replicate (and I have done this before) mysql to mariadb without worrying about their internal database structures.

Comment: I am using encrypted bin and ssl.